# There is no running instance of the task

Tags: windows, windows-7, процесс

Процесс болтается в диспетчере задач, прибить не получается (никакой ошибки нет, просто процесс как был, так и остаётся на своём месте с тем же id). При попытке прибить его из командной строки (от админа) получаю следующую ошибку:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>taskkill /f /im punto.exe
ERROR: The process "punto.exe" with PID 3972 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
```

При этом процесс по-прежнему существует.

**Что означает эта ошибка, как может не быть запущенного процесса, если id каким-то образом определяется?**

PS: Куда в итоге пропал процесс и когда это случилось, я так и не понял.

Comment: Может, зомби? (Если в винде они существуют)

Comment: Ну punto.exe это от   Punto Switcher, если отключить прогу в трее и процесс уйдёт

Comment: @Арсен, я в курсе, что это пунтосвитчер. Проблема в том, что в трее его значок даже не появлялся, а новый экземпляр запустить не получалось (вероятно из-за проверки на существование процесса).

Comment: @andreymal, я вообще только примерно в курсе, что такое зомби, но никогда не слышал, чтобы под виндой они были...

Comment: Да, taskkill не полностью вырубил, поможет перезагрузка, после появится в трее

Comment: @Арсен, сам пунтосвитчер не полностью запустился, иначе я бы не полез его прибивать - значка нет, break не работает, процесс болтается. В итоге всё-таки получилось запустить без перезагрузки и этот куда-то исчез, но я не понял, как и когда.

Comment: Вы случайно не обновляли Punto switcher? думаю переустановка поможет ))

Comment: Когда код в процессе завершился, но другие процессы держат на него дескрипторы, такое может быть.